What is the most suitable data type for a column in a table?
Currently I'm trying to develop a PostgreSQL database schema, it has only 2 tables, one of which contains usernames. The difficulty is that for certain reasons I cannot store the username directly, so I have to store the hash (SHA256).
Postgres has a bytea data type, which is an array of bytes, which is technically SHA256.
My question is whether there is a better type to store the hash in terms of speed of searching whether the username exists in the database or not.
Perhaps I should look towards NoSQL solutions, where such a search is faster?
-----Add-----
The answer and comments suggest that it is optimal to use bytea.
CREATE TABLE users (
    username bytea PRIMARY KEY,
    somedata text NOT NULL
);


If you're looking for exact matches, then would you just be hashing the input username to search and then comparing against the column?  Or, would there be other search scenarios here?

Yes I'm looking for exact matches and yes username will be hashed on the client side. But what if I choose CHAR(64) instead of bytea? Or maybe something else?

bytea is probably the most compact way of storing the hash.

Try it. As you suspected and as already confirmed in comments and the answer from @Laurenz Albe, bytea wins by being the most compact and fastest to look up.
Here's how storing 400k hashes compares between these:



variant
pg_total_relation_size
pg_size_pretty




table1_bytea
48709632
46 MB


table2_text
75530240
72 MB


table3_text_collate_c
75522048
72 MB



And here's how much time it takes to look one up:



variant
avg




hashes_in_bytea
00:00:00.00003


hashes_in_text_collate_c
00:00:00.000035


hashes_in_text
00:00:00.000042


hashes_in_text_otf
00:00:00.00011




hash index because I'm only interested in equality checks

You can't be using hash for unique indexes, so you'd need to maintain both that and the separate unique index that gets created to handle the UNIQUE constraint on your username column. I'd just stick with the default unique you already have.

Also, hash indexes are not faster.

It is probably a micro-optimization, but bytea would use significantly less space and compare faster.
If you end up using text (avoid character), make sure that you are using the C collation:
hash_value text COLLATE "C"

Other collations will result in much more expensive comparisons.

Why is bytea a micro-optimization? 32 bytes vs 64 bytes seems a significant difference if used as an index key.

@Charlieface Perhaps my wording was not great. I don't think that the performance will be much different, (using the C collation). The difference in storage can be significant.

Twice is long = twice as much to check for equality in the btree, and load and store will also be longer. I don't see how performance won't be a good bit slower.
